# compiling a c++ program including mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, gcc

I'm new to gcc, and trying to compile a c++ program which includes mysql.h using the command:

g++ -o test test.cpp -L/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -I/usr/include/mysql

It works without issue, but I was wondering if someone could explain the arguments to me. I don't like using commands I don't understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-o test` means the output file is to be named "test".

`test.cpp` is your source file, of course.

`-L/usr/include/mysql` means to look for libraries in /usr/include/mysql, as well as in the usual link path. (It probably isn't finding any libraries here; my libmysqlclient.a is in the standard library directory /usr/lib.  So I don't think you need this option.)

`-lmysqlclient` means to link with the mysqlclient library (actually named libmysqlclient.a)

`-I/usr/include/mysql` means to look for #include files in /usr/include/mysql, as well as in the usual include path.

Comment: If I'm not wrong some of them are only required when the environment macros such as LD_LIBRARY_PATH , PATH are either not set or set to different path than you are expecting.

Comment: So is his use of `-lmysqlclient` _wrong_ and should he write `-llibmysqlclient.a` instead?

Comment: @bobobobo: No. The linker adds the `lib` to the beginning and the `.a` at the end.

Comment: [Just noting I had a hell of a nightmare earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958612/libmysqlclient-a-is-nowhere-to-be-found/15958889#15958889) with not having the `.a` file on my system

Answer (score 1):

try "man g++" for a full description of what the various options mean.

Answer (score 0):

`man gcc` will give you the details of all these options.

g++ -o test test.cpp -L/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -I/usr/include/mysql

```
g++ : the compiler
-o test : name the resulting binary "test" 
test.cpp : your source file
-L : the directory to look in for libraries (that are specified by -l)
-l : named library to link against (looks for it in -L)
-I : the directory to look in for #included header files
```